# fitBounds of markers with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, fitbounds

I have a array of markers named `markers`and i add those markers in map using `LeafletJs`

```
L.layerGroup(markers).addTo(map);
```

Now i want to focus on a viewport that covers all markers

```
var bounds = L.latLngBounds(markers);
 map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [20, 20] });
```

Why i get `Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined` error message in `map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: [20, 20] });` line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because L.LatLngBounds expects two L.LatLng objects as parameter, not an array of markers, as you can see in the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds). I would suggest using [L.FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), it's extended from L.LayerGroup but has some extras. It has a `getBounds` method, which will do exactly what you need, calculate the bounds according to all of the features added to the group. So you could do:

```
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup(markers).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(featureGroup.getBounds());
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EbzlaF05fLARDYbnXSSk

Comment: I changed as you said but still has same problem.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else wrong, but can't see what based on the code you've given. Here's a working plunker, also added to my answer: [http://plnkr.co/edit/EbzlaF05fLARDYbnXSSk](http://plnkr.co/edit/EbzlaF05fLARDYbnXSSk)

Comment: Working example required "<link data-require="leaflet@1.7.3""